# Input type="radio" and hidden radio button - problems in chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have this HTML:

```
<input type="radio">
<span class="label">
    <label id="options_34537_2label" for="options_34537_2">
</label>
</span>
```

Now I also have some CSS, which hides the radio button itself and puts an image in front of my label.

```
input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}

label:before {
    background: url("someimage.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
```

In IE and FF I can click the image to select the option, in Chrome, clicking does not work at all. Any idea how to solve this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the `<input>` *inside* the `<label>` to make it cliquable:

```
<label><input type="radio"></label>
```

And use the background property on your label *directly*, instead of using the :before pseudo-class. Then add some text or specify a width to show your background.